# How to Automate trigger without User interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger a td element automatically by using (#td).trigger('click'). It works, but I dont want the user to actually click the td themselves, I just want it to be automated. I need to trigger the td element to initiate the next event. How can I trigger an element using JQuery or JS without giving the user to trigger the element. this is what I have right now...

```
$(td4).trigger('click');
//will trigger td4 which eventually will trigger td5
$(td5).trigger('click');
//which will go on to td6 and so on
```

As I said before, it works. However the user can just bypass the methods and go straight to td20 for example by simply clicking on it. I want them to go through an automated process where they have to go through all the td's in a specified order. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify a little more: Do you want the user clicking one TD to attach the click event to the next TD, or do you want to have a cascade of events happen on each successive TD without the user having to click any of them?

Comment: I don't want the user to click anything.

Comment: When you say "trigger a td element" do you mean animate it in some way? Scroll to it?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you do not want users to click the tds at all, then I don't see any purpose in having click handlers and triggering onclick through the script.

But, since you asked, below is a way to differentiate actual User click and the ones triggered through code.

You can use the event.originalEvent.isTrusted flag to check if user clicked the tds and handle it accordingly, Here's a pen for demonstration [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/ajanth2012/pen/jKabPr)

```js
 $("tr > td").click(function(e){
      if(e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.isTrusted) {
        console.log("User Click - Caught : " + e.originalEvent.isTrusted);
        e.preventDefault();
      } else {
        console.log("Clicked automatically "+ $(this).attr("id"));
        $(this).next().trigger("click");// click the next td
        
        // now trigger next td click
        // Do your stuff here
      }
    });
    


var autoClick = function(){
  $("#td1").trigger("click");
}
```

```css
td {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="15">
  <tr>
    <td id="td1">td1</td>
    <td id="td2">td2</td>
    <td id="td3">td3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="autoClick()">Click Div Through Code</button>
```

event.originalEvent.isTrusted is a flag set by the browser when user clicks on an element, it will not be set when a script triggers the click event.

Comment: How can I prevent the click from happening when I identify that the click was from the user?

Comment: Check the if condition, there i'm detecting that user clicked and using e.preventDefault to stop further execution. Your logic for automatic click  should be in else block

Comment: we cannot stop the users from clicking a td, we can only let them click and suppress the code from executing as a result

Comment: is there anyway I can just avoid the clicking all-together.

Comment: What do you mean avoid altogether ?. If you do not want users to click on TDs at all, then don't register onclick event handlers on them. Since you wanted to make trigger("click") work and not the user click, the above solution is the only way I can think of

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to handle you logic and call it via $(document).ready(yourFn());

The idea it to use jQuery to target the td's then have it iterate over them and call each of the bound event handlers correct? If not them please clarify further.

Stuff from [code pen](https://codepen.io/jrw2252/pen/OEOjGv?editors=1111) below. You can substitute the event types for the trigger parameters as needed, blur, click, etc,.:

```
    <table>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="myFnA()">R1C1</td>
    <td onclick="myFnB()">R1C2</td>
    <td onclick="myFnC()">R1C3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="myFnA()">R2C1</td>
    <td onclick="myFnB()">R2C2</td>
    <td onclick="myFnC()">R2C3</td>
  </tr>
</table>


const myFnA = () => console.log('myFnA');
const myFnB = () => console.log('myFnB');
const myFnC = () => console.log('myFnC');
const triggerTds = () => {
   $('td').trigger('click', 'blur');
};
$(document).ready(triggerTds());
```

Comment: i am already using a function but each td has its own function. and that function calls the next function

Comment: I was only referring to have your fn to be called in the .ready fn so that it would be executed on ready/automatically. Outside that you would look to have your fn call each of the bound event handlers that are set on the tds.

Comment: Look into the jQuery api for .trigger to have all targeted elements to have their event handlers to be called. Sorry about lack of code/examples, typing code on a phones no fun. https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-handler-attachment/

Comment: @gurnii to clarify what I meant about my original answer, check the code pen I threw together. https://codepen.io/jrw2252/pen/OEOjGv?editors=1111